# Current version of Zend Framework 1

Tags: zend-framework, release

Is there any feed/file online I could parse to know which version of the Zend Framework 1 is most up to date?
I'd like to be notified immediately about the security updates.

The only solution I came up so far is parsing SVN tags:

- http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/tags/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `Zend_Version::getLatest()` (which hits: http://framework.zend.com/api/zf-version).

Documentation [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.version.reading.html).

Comment: That would not inform him about security issues only about the latest version, and only if he's already running an app.

Comment: Neither would parsing the SVN tags. The wording of his question implies he only wants to know what the latest version of the 1.x branch is.

Answer (score 2):

Different feeds for different purposes

[Zend Framework Release Feed](http://devzone.zend.com/tag/Zend_Framework_Management/format/rss2.0)
--> only feeds the new version Releases

[Zend Framework Security Feed](http://framework.zend.com/security/feed)
--> feeds important security news

[Zend Framework Developer Feed](http://devzone.zend.com/tag/Zend_Framework_Developer/format/rss2.0)
--> feeds interesting (sometimes) information for devs